# Twenty Questions

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close, dupehammer

The popular tags, C, C++, Java, Android, PHP etc. already have a FAQ list and/or tag.  Users can search this and use the canonical Q&A as dupe targets.
Fine, but why are [not the OP] users doing this searching and linking?  Do they have to?

Gold badge 'Mjolnir wielders' could be given the power to hammer closed the very worst multi-duped questions say the top 20, without specifically searching for the duplicate: 'Closed as frequent duplicate, refer to FAQ: [link to FAQ, not a specific question]'.

This moves the effort of searching for the dupe from the moderator to the OP, where it belongs, and where the OP should have searched before asking.

Such 'one-click' dupe-handling would remove the need for Gold users to continually search FAQ lists for the same 'how can I compare strings in Java' Q&A and reduce the temptation to just 'answer because it's quicker', 'answer because search sucks' or other reasons to just churn out duplicate answers.

Note: I did search for 'FAQ' before this post.  There are several suggestions (from @Lundin for one) regarding finding FAQ dupes, but I did not find anything about supercharging the Thors.  I don't have my own hammers yet, but I'm fine with Gold users having such power and confidence that they would use it responsibly and effectively.

Comment: Although there is some merit closing often asked duplicates quickly I'm not sure if linking to a list is going to help future visitors, let alone the OP. The next step we close questions as duplicates because some keywords returned more then 100 questions in SE's own search engine. Whatever you propose, you need to get **the** answer to your question, not a redirect. But kudos for mentioning that tag wiki's can be of much more value, also for new OP's.

Comment: While I don't have a gold tag badges, I do frequently VTC as dupe where appropriate.  For the really common ones, I've just bookmarked them with simple titles in my browser - it's really quite quick to find the canonical Q&A for a given issue in this manner.

Comment: Maybe a more broad "This question is answered in the tag wiki, or the posts it refers to. Please read the [link]tag wiki before posting questions under a tag." is more appropriate. That way it applies more often, and can include both the tag wiki itself and the FAQ questions.

Comment: This would have to be auto-accompanied by an vote for deletion, because -- while I agree with the sentiment -- this isn't going to leave anything useful behind for the next person who _is_ conscientiously searching.

Comment: I think there's the kernel of a good idea in here. Maybe the gold badge user could be presented with a list of top 10 FAQs in a tag when they vote to close as duplicate? That way it could be a 3-click operation, instead of a search.

Comment: Hmm.. maybe closed as dup but protected from deletion?  Not sure..

Comment: You're making our content less useful for **all** users, just so you can (effectively) tell lazy users to "go search for it yourself".

Comment: @meagar no.  All users are not searching for FAQ, and those that are can find their answer in the FAQ list before searching elsewhere.

Comment: Anyway, at -5, I will consider this request dead.

Answer (score 17):

I strongly disagree with this feature.

The point of closing a question as a duplicate (as with virtually everything on the site) is to help *future users*. Any future user who lands on a question that is closed as a duplicate of a generic FAQ will have their time wasted by this feature, and it will actively harm the ability of users to find relevant answers.

Comment: I'm not convinced that the future users would consider looking at a list of 20 questions and one click on the relevant one as a waste of time - it gets them their answer with little extra effort per user.  Whether relieving those users of that task is worth Gold users continually searchng the FAQ, or issuing duplicate answers, I'm not sure.

Comment: Maybe this is not so accurate.  The larger point of closing such a question is to get it to a stage where it can easily be deleted.

Comment: The only future users who would be affected are those who don't look in the FAQ first to find their answer.  If it's there, they will not land on a question that is closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Most of our users come from Google, and they may land on closed questions. From a closed question, they should be able to reach their answer in the most direct way possible.